# How to construct a person class that allows tracking of property values over time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class

I'd like to construct a person class that has a property which the value may change over time but I want to keep the history of values. A person grows taller over time and their weight may change.  You may imagine a "HockeyPlayer: Person" that plays over many seasons.  Each season their height/weight may be different.  I would then use EntityFramework to create tables.  I think the main question I have is where do I put those properties? In their own class? In HockeyPlayer?  In Person?  Thank you in advance

pseudocode example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Season 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string season { get; set; }
}

public class HockeyPlayer : Person
{
    public int PersonId {get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }
    public int JerseyNumber { get; set; }
    public int HeightInches { get; set; }
    public int WeightPounds { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your domain model here really models what you are looking for.  Don't think of your player playing in a season as a player.  A player participates in a season and gets a record for season specific information.  So a player has a history of seasons played. a player is NOT a history of seasons.

I think I'd define something like this

```
public class Player
{
    public Player() { Seasons = new List<PlayerSeason> { }; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PlayerSeason> Seasons { get; private set; } 

    public void AddSeason(PlayerSeason playerSeason)
    {
        //some code that adds a season.  may check if already exists. whatever your business rules say to do
        Seasons.Add(playerSeason);
    }
}

public class Season 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string season { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerSeason
{
    public int PlayerId {get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }
    public int JerseyNumber { get; set; }
    public int HeightInches { get; set; }
    public int WeightPounds { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not going to get into fancier stuff like [collection encapsulation](https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core), there's enough here already to think about.

I'd take the entity classes you define here and then build your using ef-migrations.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts on the model, that helps a lot.

Comment: The only thing I would add,and it's minor, is that Player will inherit from Person because there could potentially be Coach and Manager that also inherit from Person.

Comment: I'm not sure that really works either.  A manager/coach/player is a role of a person. for a season  Can a single person be a player/coach?  if so, how are you expressing that with inheritance?

Comment: good point.  so a Person has a List of Roles in the PersonSeason?  I think my question is starting to expand unintentionally.  I'll think this through a bit more but will mark this one as the  answer.

Comment: It may be that a person has a role in a given season  then off of that depending on the role, the statistics/demographics about that role's season.  these may be different per role.  i.e. a coach may have a win/loss statistic while a player has list goals/pts,...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing some research into [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

I would create another entity called PersonMetrics with SeasonId, PersonId and Date attributes. You would then add whatever values you want to measure in that. Technically SeasonId and PersonId could form the composite primary key (in which case you would be better off putting Date on the Season entity), but for ease of use with EntityFramework, or if there will be multiple measurements per season you may choose to give it its own Id.

Comment: when you say date attributes.  Do you mean something like when an update to the person was made? so a new row, with a created date (transaction date) and the attributes that are part of that class?

Comment: Not quite, I mean SeasonId, PersonId and Date are all attributes. It might be that you don't need date if you take one measurement per season.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a separate table with  height, weight and date columns with player Id as a secondary key. Call this table PhysicalStats for example. Your HockeyPlayer would have a list of PhysicalStats rather than just single height/ weight properties as they do currently.